# Keras TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple

Tags: python, keras

I have a working Hierarchical Attention Network for text classification that uses a embedding layer made with word2vec embeddings. I want to try using a FastText model to process the data before I enter it into the model. So that I can get an embedding for every word instead of having to limit the amount of words to the dimensions of the embedding layer. So I try to remove the embedding layer and input 3 dimensional data instead (words, sentences, embedding). The model with embedding matrix looks as follows:

```
def han2(MAX_NB_WORDS, MAX_WORDS, MAX_SENTS, EMBEDDING_DIM, WORDGRU, embedding_matrix, DROPOUTPER): 

wordInputs = Input(shape=(MAX_WORDS,), dtype='float32')
wordEmbedding = embedding_layer(wordInputs)

hij = Bidirectional(GRU(WORDGRU, return_sequences=True), name='gru1')(wordEmbedding)

Si = Attention(name='att1')(hij)

wordEncoder = Model(wordInputs, Si)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

docInputs = Input(shape=(MAX_SENTS,MAX_WORDS), dtype='float32')

sentenceMasking = Masking(mask_value=0.0, name='sentenceMasking')(docInputs)

sentEncoding = TimeDistributed(wordEncoder, name='sentEncoding')(sentenceMasking) 

hi = Bidirectional(GRU(WORDGRU, return_sequences=True), merge_mode='concat', name='gru2')(sentEncoding)

Vb = Attention(name='att2')(hi)

v6 = Dense(8, activation="softmax", kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="dense")(Vb)
model = Model(inputs=[docInputs] , outputs=[v6])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

return model, wordEncoder
```

And the modified model looks like this:

```
def han2(MAX_WORDS, MAX_SENTS, EMBEDDING_DIM, WORDGRU, DROPOUTPER):

wordEmbedding = Input(shape=(MAX_WORDS,EMBEDDING_DIM,), dtype='float32')

hij = Bidirectional(GRU(WORDGRU, return_sequences=True), name='gru1')(wordEmbedding)

Si = Attention(name='att1')(hij)

wordEncoder = Model(wordEmbedding, Si)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

docInputs = Input(shape=(MAX_SENTS,MAX_WORDS,EMBEDDING_DIM,), dtype='float32')

sentenceMasking = Masking(mask_value=0.0, name='sentenceMasking')(docInputs)

sentEncoding = TimeDistributed(wordEncoder, name='sentEncoding')(sentenceMasking) 

hi = Bidirectional(GRU(WORDGRU, return_sequences=True), merge_mode='concat', name='gru2')(sentEncoding)

Vb = Attention(name='att2')(hi)

v6 = Dense(2, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="dense")(Vb)
model = Model(inputs=[docInputs] , outputs=[v6])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

return model, wordEncoder
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-2fd9fabaf093> in <module>()
  2 from keras import regularizers, constraints, optimizers
  3 
----> 4 model, model1 = han2(MAX_SENT_LENGTH, MAX_SENTS, EMBEDDING_DIM, 100, 0.2)
  5 model.summary()

<ipython-input-39-cdaf09f1852c> in han2(MAX_WORDS, MAX_SENTS, EMBEDDING_DIM, WORDGRU, DROPOUTPER)
 19     #print(sentenceMasking.shape)
 20 
---> 21     sentEncoding = TimeDistributed(wordEncoder, name='sentEncoding')(docInputs)#(sentenceMasking)
 22 
 23     #print(sentenceEncoding.shape)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
617 
618             # Actually call the layer, collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 619             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
620             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
621 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/wrappers.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
215                 uses_learning_phase = y._uses_learning_phase
216             # Shape: (num_samples, timesteps, ...)
--> 217             output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)
218             y = K.reshape(y, (-1, input_length) + output_shape[2:])
219 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/wrappers.py in compute_output_shape(self, input_shape)
174         child_output_shape = self.layer.compute_output_shape(child_input_shape)
175         timesteps = input_shape[1]
--> 176         return (child_output_shape[0], timesteps) + child_output_shape[1:]
177 
178     def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
```

I can't seem to find the problem. I've printed the shape of the different layers but I can't get the shape of the word encoder. So I can't find the problem.

Edit:
Apparently the error comes from TimeDistributed not allowing multidimensional input as described here:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3057
I don't know how to adapt the code though.

Comment: why not using the fasttext weights in the embedding layer?

Comment: I have tried using the weights in the embedding layer. But that restricts the amount of words to the embedding layer dimensions. Also I want to use fasttext to predict words not in the vocabulary when running on test data.